# is there a sandcastle plugin for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sandcastle

I really like the help files generated using SandCastle on my projects... is there a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 for SandCastle, or another good alternative program that integrates directly with Visual Studio?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) integrates directly in VS 2010.

Comment: looks pretty nice... kinda pricey though

Comment: you should disclose that you are the lead developer for VSdocman.

Answer (score 7):

SHFB has a VS2010 extension - available in the 1.9.3.4 (beta 2) release. You will need to check subsequent releases to make sure those continue to include the extension.

http://shfb.codeplex.com/releases

and details here - http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/b128ad2a-787e-48c7-b946-f6953080c386.htm

Answer (score 3):

No. Like "not yet".

Check SHFB on codeplex (SandCastle Help File Builder) - not VS integrated, but MSBuild intraetaeed.

Check DochProject on codeplex. That actually is what you want, but it is IIRC not YET out for the new version of sandcastle / Visual Studio;) Should not take long, though.

Comment: +1 Yes, shfb seems to be the way to go with .net 4.0 as well.  http://shfb.codeplex.com/